# In Java, what is the best way to share functionality between enum value?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I'm considering the best way to create common functionality between enum values, which implement an abstract method declared in the enum.
For example, I want to share the first line of the methods defined by `VALUE1` and `VALUE2`:

```
public enum EnumExample {
    VALUE1() {
       public void doSomething(String arg) {
           doSomethingElse(); // I don't want to repeat this line
           calculateFoo();
    },
    VALUE2() {
        public void doSomething(String arg) {
            doSomethingElse(); // I don't want to repeat this line
            calculateBar();
        }
    },
    VALUE3() {
        public void doSomething(String arg) {
            doSomethingUnrelated(); // This value DOES NOT share functionality with VALUE1 & VALUE2
        }
    };
    public abstract void doSomething(String arg);
}
```

Currently, I just repeat the code for each value, but I'm sure there is a better way.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the meaning of the code? Why do you have code inside an enum?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If I understand you correctly you don't want to write each time `doSomethingElse` in `doSomething`. But what makes it unclear is that in `VALUE3` you are not invoking `doSomethingElse` but `doSomethingUnrelated` which suggest that you don't actually want to always invoke `doSomethingElse` at start of `doSomething`.

Comment: @IlyaKogan Let's say I scan a string for a certain set of identifiers, when i find one of them I want to activate a different parsing functionality - so I create an enum, with property for the identifier (& a constructor to set it) and the parsing code. Later I can iterate over the enum.values method, check which of the enum values' identifier match and activate its parsing code.

Comment: @Pshemo You're right - I want to share the functionality between some of the values, not all of them.

Comment: Any solution will be more verbose, and probably repeat more code, than what you have there. It's just a method call. I wouldn't change anything to the code (except for making it compile, of course)

Comment: @JBNizet It's just a method in this simplified example - In the actual code it will probably grow to around 20 LOC;

Comment: Then extract these 20 LOC into a method of EnumExample, and call that method from the two enum constants, just as in your question.

Comment: @JBNizet I feel like it pretty weird to have this specific code, which only applies to part of the enum values "hierarchy" in all of them.

Comment: It looks like you oversimplified your example which means we ended up with [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe post another question in which you will clarify how your code looks exactly (so we would know what approaches you want to avoid) and describe what you would like to improve.

Comment: As long as it's private, you shouldn't bother. I see it as a private method called by two public methods of a class, and not by the 3 other public methods. Nothing wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is any better for you, but I like lambdas for this sort of situation. I make the `enum` implement a Functional Interface, then each value can delegate to its own private implementation.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public enum EnumExample implements Consumer<String> {
    VALUE1(t -> {
        doSomethingElse();
        calculateFoo();
    }),

    VALUE2(t -> {
        doSomethingElse();
        calculateFoo();
    }),

    VALUE3(t -> doSomethingUnrelated());

    private final Consumer<String> myLambda;

    EnumExample(Consumer<String> aLambda) {
        myLambda = aLambda;
    }

    static void doSomethingElse() {}

    static void calculateFoo() {}

    static void doSomethingUnrelated() {}

    @Override
    public void accept(String t) {
        myLambda.accept(t);
    }
}
```

It still repeats your method calls, but it looks cleaner to my eyes.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the "generic" operation on the "base enum class" and define the specific operation as abstract, so it must be implemented:

```
enum EnumExample {

    VALUE1 {
        @Override
        void doSomethingSpecific() {
            System.out.println("specific for " + VALUE1);
        }
    },
    VALUE2 {
        @Override
        void doSomethingSpecific() {
            System.out.println("specific for" + VALUE2);
        }
    };


    public void doSomething(){
        doSomethingGeneric();
        doSomethingSpecific();
    }
    void doSomethingGeneric(){
        System.out.println("Same for all enums...");
    };
    abstract void doSomethingSpecific();
}
```